# Can two MDI forms be in one group of projects and call (show) form MDIForm2 from project Project1?

Tags: forms, project, call, mdi, group

I have two ready projects Project1 and Project2 in vb6. In the projects there are by one mdi forms
MDIForm1 and MDIForm2. The app must work like that: first an enter form shows. In the form one from two options selects. In dependence on the selection MDIForm1 or MDIForm2 shows. But when I add form MDIForm2 into the project Project1 following error arises: Only one MDI form can add in project.
I have an idea to create a group from two projects. I have a question:
Can two MDI forms be in one group of projects and call (show) form MDIForm2 from project Project1?

I tried to add second project. It was added. But I could not call (show) MDIForm2 in project Project1.